# From these two options, which one is better toward becoming a Professor in a high-ranking university?

Tags: postdocs, university, early-career, assistant-professor

Let's say you've just finished your PhD.(EECS), your ultimate goal is to become a Professor from any high-ranking University (world top 100). You are presented with two main options.

Option 1: Starting at once as an Assistant Professor in a low-ranking University (world top 3000), with clear options to become fast enough an Associate (after 4 or 5 years) and then maybe, try to apply to a better ranked University of your likeness.

Option 2: Enrolling in a Post-Doctoral 2 or 3 years in a high-ranking University (world top 100) and then try to apply for an Assistant Professor position at a simlarly high or slightly lower-ranked University.

In short, Low-ranked Professor position vs High-ranked Post-Doctoral position?
What is the way to go toward a High-ranked Professor position?

Comment: You are trying to predict the future, which is impossible to answer.  You could go to a top or low ranking university, but failed miserably due to many factors.  Yes, top universities  have more prepared students, but say they do not want to work with you.    Same with resources, more $ but more sharks too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, neither is better, or worse. The goal, while extremely unlikely to be met (statistically), can be achieved in either scenario, but will depend on other things, not the particular choice here. And two of those factors are just timing and chance.

Even if, statistically, one could be shown to correlated more highly with the goal than the other, the numbers of entry positions in a given field in those top 100 institutions in a given year (or short time span) are so small as to make the stats meaningless. And you don't speak the language for lots of them, I expect.

And even if you could get such an offer, you might not want to take it based on other factors such as place (country/city/language), likelihood of success there, and other personal things. Cambridge (Massachusetts, or UK) is a great place, but not for everyone.

It is good to have goals and to shoot high, but if you want to be a success in top (i.e. research oriented) universities then you need to do a lot of research, produce a lot of quality papers, probably with a lot of collaborators. If you do that, and can also teach effectively, especially upper level students, then you might have a shot along with millions of other aspirants with more coming along every year.

Note that each of those top 100 institution, not unlike all the others, has its own goals and, while they overlap a lot, aren't the same. Some, I know (been there) put a lot of emphasis on undergraduate education. Others just treat it as a necessary task. Still others don't deal with it at all, I'd guess.

Take a look at the current [world ranking of universities](https://www.webometrics.info/en/world) to get an idea about the diversity of universities. Those around a ranking of 2500 or so are so vastly different from the top 100 that starting a career there would make it quite difficult to move to the top just because of the much lower opportunity (not zero) to do quality visible research.

But [Srinivasa Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) moved up from the University of Madras (currently around 2000) to Cambridge. It isn't impossible, but there was both luck and the sponsorship of Hardy involved. And few are the equal of Ramanujan in any case.

And, you don't indicate the perceived level of the university from which you just graduated. If it is in the top 50 or so, then you have a better shot, just because, if you played the game wisely, you have a lot of professors who can predict your success. That itself can be a big factor, even if it wasn't the top 50. If your professors are known and can vouch for you then you have a shot.

tl/dr: Other factors dominate. Think more broadly. Think more about your overall quality of life than about the ranking of the place you will work.

Comment: Ramanujan lived in a very different world. Today's world is so hardly strucutred and bureaucratic (with the final goal of increasing productivity) that whatever merit is killed at the very beginning.

Comment: @EarlGrey, perhaps, but he wasn't given much of any advantage in his situation, different, perhaps, but not better.

Comment: He had the huge advantage that he could speak at the research level with peers before he could speak with them about formal stuff (employment, etcetc). On top of that, in that time his peers were strongly involved and responsible for hiring new faculties. Nowadays there is a selection comitee, where quite often the math faculty has the same weight as the person responsible for the estate property management. Nowadays, even the sponsorship of Hardy would not be enough.

Comment: Ramanujan is probably a 'god' level example.  There many other examples whereby a bright student from a developing country gets plucked out of obscurity into a top university.